# How to optimise react typography component?

Tags: react-component

I have code:

```
const H1 = ({style, children}) => {
    return <h1 className={styleMap[style]}>{children}</h1>
}

const H2 = ({style, children}) => {
    return <h2 className={styleMap[style]}>{children}</h2>
}
```

My goal is to reduce repeated code, so that I will have something like:

```
const H{number} = ({style, children}) => {
        return <h{number} className={styleMap[style]}>{children}</h{number}>
    }
```

But I would be able to call it like

```
<H1 style='style5'>Main Title</H1>
<H2 style='style2'>Subtitle</H2>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here.  If your goal is to have an element that doesn't pass props or children, then you aren't making an HOC, you're just making a shorthand for your HTML.

Comment: Though the intended usage looks redundant and not worthy, it's a valid question nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const H{number} = ({style, children}) => {
  return <h{number} className={styleMap[style]}>{children}</h{number}>
}
```

This syntax you want is not possible. But you can dynamically decide which header level you wanna you by passing in a prop.

```js
function Header(props) {
  const { level, style, children } = props
  if (Number.isInteger(level) && level >= 1 && level <= 6) {
    return React.createElement(`h${level}`, { className: styleMap[style] }, children)
  } else {
    throw Error('Invalid "level" prop, must be number 1-6')
  }
}

// Usage:
<Header level={1} style='style5'>Main Title</Header>
```

You have to resort to the plain JS `React.createElement` syntax, cus JSX doesn't allow you to use dynamic value for component, it's simply syntax error to write `<{whatever} />` in JSX.

Comment: I can only guess you're just taking this as an example to post the question. Must say such component is not worth building, cus that's actually way more code than just use `<h1 />`.